# Backfill data frame in R based on maximum number

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a number of id's and max values.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), max.number = c(0, 6, 4))

  id max.number
1  a          0
2  b          6
3  c          4
```

I want to create a new data frame that backfills down to zero for each id.  It would look like:

```
  id     number
1  a          0
2  b          0
3  b          1
4  b          2
5  b          3
6  b          4
7  b          5
8  b          6
9  b          0
10 c          1
11 c          2
12 c          3
13 c          4
```

I've tried to do this through a nested for loop but can't get it to work correctly.  I would love some guidance in doing this with apply if possible.

Comment: You could go with `id <- lapply(df$max.number, seq, from=0) ;
data.frame(id=rep(df$id, lengths(id)), num=unlist(id))`

Comment: You'll find useful `?rep` for "id" and `?sequence` for "max.number"

Comment: @user20650 That worked perfectly.  Thanks!  Making sure I understand the process.  Using lapply, a list is created with vectors from 0 to my max number.  Then a data frame is created by repeating the id for the length of each vector with the id list and unlisting the id list.  Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, (and yup thats right)

Comment: `with(df, data.frame(id = rep(id, max.number + 1), number = sequence(max.number + 1) - 1))` or `df[[2]] <- Map(seq, 0, df$max.number); tidyr::unnest(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be very easy with a [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) table:

```
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), max.number = c(0, 6, 4))
dt <- as.data.table(df) 
# or directly: 
# dt <- data.table(id = c("a", "b", "c"), max.number = c(0, 6, 4))
dt[, .(number=seq(0, max.number)), by=id]
```

Output:

```
    id number
 1:  a      0
 2:  b      0
 3:  b      1
 4:  b      2
 5:  b      3
 6:  b      4
 7:  b      5
 8:  b      6
 9:  c      0
10:  c      1
11:  c      2
12:  c      3
13:  c      4
```